# Using Doctrine in a custom Symfony command?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, command

I created a custom Symfony command to manage entities in my DB but I don't know how to use doctrine in it (e.g. import it like in a controller).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ContainerAwareCommand is fine.

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the container directly is not a good practice. Sometimes you will need to modify class code and when that time comes you will need to review the whole code to find any dependencies.

Register the command as a serivce and pass serivces that are actually will be used in the logic.

Check [How to Define Commands as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html)